# How to keep escape keys from a json?

Tags: json, dart

I´m making an application with dart / flutter and I need to keep the escape keys from the json server api response, how can I do that?

Example:

> JSON reponse:

```
{"\"\"example\"\"": "value\'"}
```

> Goal (after .fromJson and json.decode):

`Class.example = "\"\"example\"\"";`

`Class.value = "value\'";`

Comment: What are you doing now? What's not working?

Comment: I´m using json.decode to convert the response to Object, but he apply the escape keys: if the json value is "\"\"example\"\"" he transforms into "example", I want it to keep the escape keys and not apply them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `jsonDecode(r'{"\"\"example\"\"": "value\'"}')`, then you get a map with the key `""example""` and the value `value'` (the quotes are part of the string content here, not delimiters).
The backslashes are removed, which is to be expected because that's what the JSON specification says should happen. The escaped quotes are retained. The key does not become just `example`.

If you want to retain the backslashes too, then you don't actually want JSON decoding, because JSON decoding treats `\"` inside a string literal as introducing the character `"`.

If you wanted a string containing `\"\"example\"\"` from JSON decoding, then the original source needed to be `"\\\"\\\"example\\\"\\\""`.
So, if the sender of the JSON wanted you to see backslashes, they should have included and escaped those backslashes too.

If you JSON encode the string back, you get the backslashes again (at least for `"`), since `jsonEncode('""example""')` is `"\"\"example\"\""`.

If you really want access to the *source code* of the JSON input, I'd use a non-standard JSON parser, one which allows you to access the source instead of only the parsed value.

Example:

```dart
import "package:jsontool/jsontool.dart";

/// Parses [source] as JSON, but retains source escapes in strings.
Object? readJsonSourceStrings(String source) {
  return _readJson(JsonReader.fromString(source));
}

Object? _readJson(JsonReader<StringSlice> reader) {
  if (reader.tryObject()) {
    var map = <String, Object?>{};
    while (reader.hasNextKey()) {
      var keySlice = reader.nextKeySource()!;
      var key = keySlice.substring(1, keySlice.length - 1);
      map[key] = _readJson(reader);
    }
    return map;
  } 
  if (reader.tryArray()) {
    var list = <Object?>[];
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      list.add(_readJson(reader));
    }
    return list;
  } 
  if (reader.checkString()) {
    var slice = reader.expectAnyValueSource();
    return slice.substring(1, slice.length - 1);
  }
  return reader.tryNum() ?? reader.tryBool() ?? 
      (reader.tryNull() ? null : (throw "Unreachable"));
}

void main() {
  var m = readJsonSourceStrings(r'''{"\"\"example\"\"":"value\'"}''');
  print(m); // {\"\"example\"\": value\'}
}
```

(Disclaimer: I wrote the `jsontool` package.)